# How to deal with $\vec{j}\cdot\vec{A}$ or $\rho A^2$ interaction when utilizing Kubo formula? Gauge invariance?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, gauge-invariance, greens-functions

If there exist electromagnetic fields in solids, electrons can feel interactions like $\vec{j} \cdot \vec{A}$ or $\rho A^2$ (these are not regarded as perturbations). But these are not gauge invariant. Then we add some other perturbation fields to study their corresponding linear response. I can't see whether brute-force [Kubo formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula) evaluation gives gauge invariant result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Kubo formula, you often have to calculate vertex functions. You'd better take care of gauge invariance by imposing Ward-Takahashi identity onto them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics Stackexchange. As is, this answer would be more eligible as a comment. Would you care to expand it into a more more full and self-contained answer?